# MySqlDataReader retrieves information just one time

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

I am creating an app that is connecting to MySQL database. Here is my code:

```
  System.String result = "";

        try
        {
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader;
            string selectCmd = "SELECT * FROM " + table;

            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand command = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(selectCmd, m_Connection);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result += ((string)reader[column]);
                result += ";";
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return result;
```

It retrieves data just the first time. The second, third etc. it is returning "".

Comment: You should debug and see if there is an exception happening on that second run. I suspect it might be related to the reader not being closed.

Comment: first you should run the query in phpmayadmin or mysql workbench, to be sure there are data available in that column. I personally would add some code the see if a error ouccurs and especially which.